# How can I trigger a 'yum clean all' from within a yum plugin?

Tags: centos, fedora, redhat, rpm, yum

I'm writing a yum plugin that updates the URLs of local repos. When the repo URL changes, I'd like to have yum run a `yum clean all` to make sure no out-of-date information is cached. I know yum has a hook for running code when `yum clean [plugins|all]` is requested but is it possible to trigger a clean all from within one of the plugin's other hook functions?

Comment: I assume your plugin is doing something with the metadata? Because by default yum detects URLs changing (at least on my F16 machine) and runs makecache itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm modifying the repo URL only in certain circumstances. It doesn't seem to detect this likely because it is done after initialization. This is why I'm thinking I need to add my own check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily. Yum exposes a library which is consumed by command line program. Here is an example code for yum clean all:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/share/yum-cli")
import cli
ybc = cli.YumBaseCli()
ybc.cleanCli(["all"])
```

In case you want to do more then "clean all" using function check all the APIs exposed by CLI library methods exposed at /user/share/yum-cli folder :)

Regards,